# statement in the form of a question?

Tags: questions, rules

So in Jeopardy!, and a few other media, there are answers to the statements, and the contestants find the question. What I am wondering is, why do they answer with something like, "What is ________?" Why is this? Furthermore, what are the rules for this?

Comment: You're supposed to answer with a question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a game show format, not English in general.

Comment: @CJDennis I don't think that's fair since the asker probably doesn't *know* that this is a quirk of a particular game show rather than a general fact about English.

Comment: @TannerSwett your correct in that assumption.

Comment: @TannerSwett Ignorance of that fact (which is perfectly reasonable for a learner) does not make this question on topic for English, but rather for games shows and television. Note that your answer is also about the game show and even says it's not a feature of English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know, in the game show *Jeopardy!*, questions are given in the form of statements and contestants must answer in the form of question. For example, the question may be "This city in Michigan is famous for automobile manufacturing," and contestants must answer "What is Detroit?"

There is no grammatical reason why *Jeopardy!* is like that; it's just a quirk of the show.

According to [the Wikipedia article about *Jeopardy!*](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Jeopardy!&oldid=943133416#Conception_and_development), in the original idea for the show, contestants would be given genuine answers such as "5,280" and would have to respond with the most appropriate question—in this case, "How many feet are in a mile?" However, the format evolved from there; nowadays, the clues are simply questions phrased as statements, rather than statements which would genuinely be the answer to a question.

Nowadays, people speaking English do sometimes give answers in the form of a question like on *Jeopardy!*. Whenever they do that, they're making a deliberate reference to the game show.